# Windows Firewall blocking port when specific program is selected

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-firewall

I developed a C# application with an asp.net webapi server. When I send a request from the local machine it works fine. I then created an incoming firewall rule to open the port.

**The problem:** When I limit the rule to my specific executable, other devices on the network can't reach my server. Changing the setting to "all programs" makes everything work again.

Do you have any idea why this is not working with the specific executable selected?

[image: Windows Firewall Settings]

**Edit:**

Here is my config (from Get-NetFirewallRule).

```
Name                  : {49D367A1-E670-4A4A-9FC1-ED91A38C35BF}
DisplayName           : Android Handoff (private)
Description           :
DisplayGroup          :
Group                 :
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Private
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Allow
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
Owner                 :
PrimaryStatus         : OK
Status                : Die Regel wurde erfolgreich vom Speicher aus analysiert. (65536)
EnforcementStatus     : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource     : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType : Local
```

Settings from the UI:

```
Protocol and Ports:  
- local port: 9000  
- remote port: any  
Scope:  
- local IP: any  
- remote IP: local subnet  
Advanced:  
- Edge exception: allowed  
- profile:  private and domain
Programs and Services:  
- program: explained above  
- application packages: all  
- services: all  
- depots: all  
General:  
- action: allow connection
```

Comment: can you show the rest of the settings? Get-NetFirewallRule -name "Android Handoff" etc.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with etc, I added as much config as I could find.

Comment: did you check %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log after enabling logging for both denied and allowed packets?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Great hint so far! It looks like I receive packages through the private profile when I allow all programs to use the specified port. When I only allow my specific program, the packages are denied by the public profile. I am in a private network (checked on both computers). Adding the same firewall rule for the public profile did not help either.